# Loop for choosing next array element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a loop that chooses next array element after the click, the problem is that it iterates all at once and gives me all array elements. Here is my code :

```
head_button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    change_head();
    dwarf.appendChild(head);
}, false);

function change_head() {
    var head_class = [
        {name: "bold"},
        {name: "rainbow_head"},
        {name: "hut_head"},
        {name: "beats_head"}
    ];
    for (let i = 0; i < head_class.length; i++){
        head.classList.add(head_class[i].name);
        break;
    }
};
```

Hope it's possible

Answer (score 3):

Create variable that will hold number, and based on that variable, select next element from array.

## Edit

I thought you would like to remove old class so here is updated code.

```
let current = 0;
var head_class = [
    {name: "bold"},
    {name: "rainbow_head"},
    {name: "hut_head"},
    {name: "beats_head"}
];
function change_head() {
    head.classList.remove(head_class[current].name); // remove current
    if(++current > head_class.length) current = 0;
    head.classList.add(head_class[current].name); // add new
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `head_class` and `i` *outside* the event handler, and don't use a loop, since you only want to advance by one each time the user clicks:

```
head_button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    change_head();
    dwarf.appendChild(head);
}, false);

var head_class = [
    {name: "bold"},
    {name: "rainbow_head"},
    {name: "hut_head"},
    {name: "beats_head"}
];
var i = 0;
function change_head() {
    if (i < head_class.length) {
        head.classList.add(head_class[i].name);
        ++i;
    }
}
```

Ideally, don't put all this in global scope, since the global scope is already really crowded.

For instance:

```js
// Scoping function 
(function() {
    var head_button = document.getElementById("head_button");
    
    head_button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        change_head();
        //dwarf.appendChild(head);
    }, false);
    
    var head_class = [
        {name: "bold"},
        {name: "rainbow_head"},
        {name: "hut_head"},
        {name: "beats_head"}
    ];
    var i = 0;
    function change_head() {
        if (i < head_class.length) {
            head.classList.add(head_class[i].name);
            ++i;
        }
    }
})();
```

```css
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.rainbow_head {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.hut_head {
  color: green;
}
.beats_head {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="head_button" value="Click Me">
<div id="head">This is head</div>
```

This will only go through the elements once. If you wanted to loop, you could change:

```
++i;
```

to

```
i = (i + 1) % head_class.length;
```

---

Side note: You seem to be trying to reuse `head` in multiple calls to `appendChild` on the same parent element (`dwarf`). Note that when you do that, the element isn't *copied*. It's only appended once, and then you're modifying the element.

Comment: Mind that your way it will stop at last element and do nothing. It would be cool to go back when `i = head_class.length`

Comment: @Oen44 - Done. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
head_button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    change_head(e);
    dwarf.appendChild(head);
}, false);

function change_head() {
    var head_class = [
        {name: "bold"},
        {name: "rainbow_head"},
        {name: "hut_head"},
        {name: "beats_head"}
    ];
    let nextElement = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < head_class.length; i++){
        if(e.target.value === head_class[i]) nextElememnt = true;
        if(nextElement){
        head.classList.add(head_class[i].name);
        break;
}

    }
};
```